# How can I extract detail of the exception by giving the TDetail of the FaultException in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, faultexception

The response of the SOAP request is the following xml output.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">INVALID_REQUEST - Request is not a valid for XSD rules.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ServiceError xmlns="http://test.test.com/xmlschema/common">
                <code>INVALID_REQUEST</code>
                <description>Request is not a valid for XSD rules.</description>
                <details>cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '?' is not a valid value for 'integer'.</details>
                <details>cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '?' of element 'pos:userId' is not valid.</details>
            </ServiceError>
        </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

While trying to catch this error with FaultException, I created the ServiceError class as below and gave it as TDetail to FaultException. However, I could not catch the details of this error.It doesn't come inside the catch block at all. Where am I going wrong or is there a method you recommend?

```
        try{
           //here is the code where i got the error
        }
        catch (FaultException<ServiceError> e)
        {
        }
    
        [DataContract]
        public class ServiceError
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string code { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string description { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string[] details { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method,
The detail node of the message failure should contain XML. 
GetDetail will deserialize this XML into the given object.For details you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523399/extracting-detail-from-a-wcf-faultexception-response).

The content is a string, the code:

```
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    MessageFault msgFault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
   var msg = msgFault.GetReaderAtDetailContents().Value;
     //throw Detail
}
```

If the details are not strings, the code:

```
MessageFault msgFault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
XmlReader readerAtDetailContents = msgFault.GetReaderAtDetailContents();
var readOuterXml = readerAtDetailContents.ReadOuterXml(); 
var data = XElement.Parse(readOuterXml);
Dictionary<string, string> element = data.Elements().ToDictionary(elementKey => elementKey.Name.LocalName, elementVal => elementVal.Value, null);
```